# Connect SYS DBA with no password using JAVA

Tags: java, sql, oracle, thin

I want to connect oracle DB with JAVA, I have code like this :

```
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:DB";
    con = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, "sys as sysdba" , "");
    return con;
```

it's not working, but I tried with command promt like this conn /as sysdba, it can be Connected. I have beed googling about this article but all of code not work.

Anyone can help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try catching the exception, it must provide more information about the problem.

```
 public static Connection getConnection(String name, String pass) {
    connection = null;
    try {
        Class.forName(JDBC_DRIVER);
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, name, pass);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return connection;
}
```

Do you get the same error when trying to connect with a different username and password instead of "sys as sysdba" , "" ?

Also, in the dbURL, check if the url and database name are set correctly.

The problem most likely lies in the empty password. Try substituting "" with "()". If the sys really uses empty password, it must work. If it doesn't help, consider changing the password manually by alter user

Comment: Got Error NULL user or password using THIN driver.

Comment: Ok. The problem most likely lies in the empty password. Try substituting "" with "()". If it doesn't help, consider changing the password manually by alter user

Answer (score 0):

To log on as SYSDBA with the JDBC Thin driver you must configure the server to use the password file. So you need to provide password for sys.